# Angular 12 + material: Regular expression too large

Tags: angular, angular-material, ivy

I have updated our application to Angular v12.
In Chrome, I get this error (after successfull compilation):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
> /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?:T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:.\d+)?(?:Z|(?:(?:+|-)\d{2}:\d{2}))?)?$/:
> Regular expression too large

This regex can be found in node_modules/@angular/material/bundles/material-core.umd.js at line #854:

> ```
> var ISO_8601_REGEX = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?:T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?(?:Z|(?:(?:\+|-)\d{2}:\d{2}))?)?$/;
> ```

In Angular 11, we didn't get this error, so I'm wondering why it's appearing now, and how to solve this. I have already tried to downgrade @angular/material to v11, but it trows the exact same error.

**package.json's dependencies:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.14",
    "core-js": "^2.6.2",
    "cypress": "^8.2.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-movie": "^3.0.6",
    "cypress-promise": "^1.1.0",
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.4.0",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^1.7.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.5",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "tslib": "~2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.14",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "0.0.23",
    "ng-packagr": "^12.2.6",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "release-it": "^14.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird. Maybe it's not related with your project.

If you use Chrome 95 it could be linked to this bug
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1264014

What you can do is update your browser or try with another ( firefox for exemple ) if it's work it's definitly Chrome related

Comment: Chrome is up-to-date to version 96.0.4664.110.
Edge: same error 
Firefox: Error: inject() must be called from an injection context